# MySQL join 2 tables but rename columns because they have the same name

Tags: php, mysql, join, identity-column

I have 2 tables,

admin, pricing

- admin contains columns (id, date_created, type, value)
- pricing contains columns (id, date_created, relation, value)

I want to do a select that joins the two tables where pricing.relation = admin.id

How do I rename the value, id and date_created rows so they do not overwrite each other?

This is the kinda thing i'm trying:

```
$sub_types = $database->query('
    SELECT 
    pricing.*,
    admin.*
        FROM 
        pricing,
        admin
            WHERE pricing.relation = admin.id
');
```

Comment: You can use the `AS` operator here, i.e. `pricing.id as price_id`

Comment: Exactly - AS it the thing you want to use. Not only it will help you with the duplicate names, but it also encourages you to use only those columns you really want :)
I mean: do we always want ALL the columns when using "SELECT *" ? Or are we just lazy to manually type the columns we really want? :)

Comment: lazy... etc. :) problem? hehehehe

Comment: No problem at all. I do the same :) I am just saying...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use aliases:

```
SELECT p.id as pid, 
       p.date_created as pricing_date, 
       p.type, p.value as pricing_value,
       a.id as aid, 
       a.date_created as admin_date,
       a.relation, 
       a.value as admin_value
FROM pricing p
inner join admin a on p.relation = a.id
```

Comment: You just gave me an idea how to solve a different problem thanks.